# How to pass Array in symfony route?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a function in my controller that takes an array as input. The value is passed from ajax. At the moment it is not being decoded correctly.

```
 /**
 * @Route("/userLogin/{params}", name="userLogin", methods={"POST"})
 * @param UserdbRepository $repository
 * @param $params
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */

public function userLogin(UserdbRepository $repository, $params) {

   $email = $params[0];
   $pass = $params[1];

   print_r($params);  // output correct value test@test.com
   echo $params[0];   // output t
   echo $email;       // output t

   .... rest of code
}
```

js:

```
 const array = [ 'email', 'pass' ]

 $.ajax({
    url: `/userLogin/${array}`,
    type: "post",
    dataType: 'json'
})
```

Comment: Instead of print_r, try using var_dump to display the variable. That will also give you the type. In this type of case, I assume the value isn't an array but is an object that implements array access or some magic method to allow print_r.

Comment: you are right it was a weird javascript object; I renamed the topic and edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Request` component `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request` you can autowire it: `public function userLogin(UserdbRepository $repository, Request $request)`

Example 1: fetch params from `requestBody`:

`$email = $request->request->get('email', null);`

`$email` will be `null` if `'email'` parameter not provided in request

don't forget to pass `data` property in your ajax request

```
const requestBody = {
    'email': 'asd@example.com',
    'pass': '123',
};

$.ajax({
    url: `/userLogin/`,
    type: "post",
    data: requestBody,
});
```

Note: don't send data in `json` format. Also you can remove {params} from your `@Route` pattern and `$params` argument.

Example 2: fetch `'email'` param from `queryString`:

`$email = $request->query->get('email', null);`

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html

Comment: I edited the question, just found it was a javascript object. not sure if your answer is still good ?

Comment: did you try this code out? Seems that in the question, it is a type error of the $email variable!

Comment: Can you provide what is ${array} value in the end?

Comment: I'd suggest to generate normal string for `url`, or put this `array` Object in request body (you need `key: value` pairs)

Comment: `url: '/userLogin/?email=asd@example.com&password=123',`
but again, write this sensitive information in request body

Comment: by "request body" you mean adding a `data` parameter to the ajax request ?

Comment: Yes, but don't send in json format, if you want to use these examples. just send form-data

Comment: That was it. had to use body request. If you edit your answer I'll accept it.